# Laravel total foreach index number

Tags: laravel, foreach

I want to total all the rows to loop, what do I do?

example :

index 0
ixdex 1

I want this ซ

index 2

My code :

```
     @if(isset($unread[$messages_conversation_teachers->conversation_id]))
                                  
       @foreach($unread[$messages_conversation_teachers->conversation_id] as $_index =>$unreads)

         {{$_index}}

       @endforeach

      @endif
```

Comment: simply you need to increment key while showing like this  {{++$_index}}

Comment: I want it to sum up how many index are.

Comment: {{ $_index->count() }} this way should got your count of indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `$loop->iteration` it start from `1` not `0`

```php
 @if(isset($unread[$messages_conversation_teachers->conversation_id]))
                                  
       @foreach($unread[$messages_conversation_teachers->conversation_id] as $_index =>$unreads)

         {{ $loop->iteration }}

       @endforeach

      @endif
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: No, I want it to sum up how many index are.

Comment: `$loop->count The total number of items in the array being iterated.`  ?